# Dropdown menu that opens with mouseover and click event only flickering

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a dropdown menu that opens upon clicking a button, or hovering over it.

With the code I have, the dropdown menu flickers upon clicking or hovering. In other words, the display and opacity doesn't stay. I want to be able to either click or hover over the dropdown menu header to display the dropdown menu.

HTML:

```
<div class="menu-link dropdown">
    <p class="dropdown-select">Item</p>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <div class="top">
            <div class="arr-wrap">
                <div class="arr"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p class="menu-link"><a href="./link.html">Item</a></p>
        <p class="menu-link"><a href="./link.html">Item</a></p>
        <p class="menu-link"><a href="./item.html">Item</a></p>
        <p class="menu-link"><a href="./item.html">Item</a></p>
        <p class="menu-link"><a href="./item.html">Item</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu-link {
    width: 100px;
    text-align: right;
    transition: 0.3s;
    margin-right: 25px;
}
.dropdown .menu-link {
    width: 200px;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 15px 0px;
    margin-left: 35px;
    height: 25px;
}
.dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    opacity: 0;
    width: fit-content;
    height: fit-content;
    margin-left: -8px;
    width: fit-content;
    flex-flow: column;
    z-index: 3;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: 0.2s;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px lightgrey;
    display: none;
}

.dropdown-select {
    height: fit-content;
}


.menu .menu-link {
    width: 100px;
    text-align: right;
    transition: 0.3s;
    margin-right: 25px;
}
.dropdown .menu-link {
    width: 200px;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 15px 0px;
    margin-left: 35px;
    height: 25px;
}
.dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    opacity: 0;
    width: fit-content;
    height: fit-content;
    margin-left: -8px;
    width: fit-content;
    flex-flow: column;
    z-index: 3;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: 0.2s;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px lightgrey;
    display: none;
}
.dropdown-select {
    height: fit-content;
}
.display {
    display: flex;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', load, false);

function load() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown")[0].addEventListener("click", dropdown, false);
    document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown")[0].addEventListener("mouseover", dropdown, false);
}

function dropdown() {
    var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-menu")[0];
    
    dropdown.classList.toggle("display");
}
```

Comment: I searched for "Pure css dropdown menu"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an easy mistake:
The menu flickers because "mouseover" triggers every time the mouse moves over the element just by a tiny bit. so when you move the mouse over the dropdown menu, mouseover it's constantly calling the function which toggles the "display" class, so it opens, then it closes, then it opens again, and so on to infinity.

to fix it, you should try something like this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown")[0].addEventListener("click", dropdownClick, false);
document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown")[0].addEventListener("mouseenter", dropdownMouseEnter, false);
document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown")[0].addEventListener("mouseleave", dropdownMouseLeave, false);

function dropdownClick() {
    var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-menu")[0];
    dropdown.classList.toggle("display");
}

function dropdownMouseEnter() {
    var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-menu")[0];
    dropdown.classList.add("display");
}

function dropdownMouseLeave() {
    var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-menu")[0];
    dropdown.classList.remove("display");
}
```

This is not the best way to go on about making a dropdown menu, but this will make what you have work a lot better and more like you first intended.

As said before mouseover will trigger every time the mouse cursor moves over the element, while mouseenter will trigger once on mouse first hovering the element, and mouseleave will trigger it once more when the mouse is no longer hovering the element.

I've taken the liberty to rework it a bit to make it more functional. See below for the result:

```js
function _(id) { return document.getElementById(id); }

_("dropdown1").addEventListener("click", dropdownClick, false);
_("dropdown1").addEventListener("mouseenter", dropdownMouseEnter, false);
_("dropdown1").addEventListener("mouseleave", dropdownMouseLeave, false);

function dropdownClick() {
    _("dropdown1").classList.toggle("show");
}

function dropdownMouseEnter() {
    _("dropdown1").classList.add("show");
}

function dropdownMouseLeave() {
    _("dropdown1").classList.remove("show");
}
```

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: #eee;
    margin: 0.5rem;
}

.dropdown-wrap {
    position: absolute;
}

.dropdown-wrap .menu-link {
    padding: 1rem;
}

.dropdown-wrap .dropdown-select {
    padding: 1rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 7rem;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 0.8rem;
}

.dropdown {
    min-width: 12rem;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    left: 0;
    top: calc(100% + 0.5rem);
    z-index: 3;
    border-radius: 0.8rem;
    transition: 0.2s;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px lightgrey;
    transform-origin: top left;
    scale: 0;
}

.dropdown-wrap.show .dropdown {
    scale: 1;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-wrap">
    <p class="dropdown-select">Item</p>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <p class="menu-link"><a href="./link.html">Item</a></p>
        <p class="menu-link"><a href="./link.html">Item</a></p>
        <p class="menu-link"><a href="./item.html">Item</a></p>
        <p class="menu-link"><a href="./item.html">Item</a></p>
        <p class="menu-link"><a href="./item.html">Item</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this and it's still flickering. I even commented out the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` event listeners and when I click on the header item every other time I click it, it flickers. Do you have any idea why that may be?

Comment: I've updated the answer with a fix and a working example based on your code.  Have a look at my solution and how I made it work